# How can load Model function in block when overide or extend a core magento block

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

[image]

Please Explain me in Magento 2.0 (Only Override Case)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Following way you can get object manager instance

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

Now you can get/create any model or model collection. Here is an example of order collection.

```
$orderCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()
```

Comment: Great :) I am use ->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Orde') like this

Comment: OM should never be instantiated directly, this contradicts the basics of M2 architecture. It will at least be impossible to write unit tests for such classes. See response from @KAndy.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2 constructor is not part of public API and you can change it (add more dependencies). And you should do not call ObjectManager direct.

in your case, add constructor with order factory

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config $configCacheType,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
   parent::__construct(...);
   $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
```

and in method hello use it

```
public function hello()
{
    return $this->collectionFactory->create()->load();
}
```

Comment: I use this and pass __contruct($context,$data) but showing error ==> Object DOMDocument should be created

Comment: you should  pass all parameters declared in parent to parent constructor